# Detonating a spice bloom in the middle of a spice field. Gain or Loss?

Tags: dune-2

In Dune2, detonating a solitary spice bloom surrounded by sand will yield a spice field. Sometimes one can find a bloom in the middle of a spice field. In order to maximize credits, should I attempt to harvest the field around it first or detonate it straight away? Will there be any difference?

Comment: Pretty sure you should  get more spice if you harvest around it first, but the stupid harvesters will often run over them while harvesting so not sure if its worth the effort of micro managing that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For max profit, collect the spice around the bloom first, then detonate the spice bloom. A spice field can only hold certain amount of spice in them and any excessive spice is "wasted", AKA lost. Darker the spice field is, the more spice it has in it.

It can also serve as good "back up", in case you end up without any field in late game, allowing you to create new fields.

Also, unless my memory is playing a trick on me, more blooms will appear over time, so you never truly run out of spice.

Comment: I've never seen new blooms show up.  In fact most of the maps were static and the locations of blooms never change.

Comment: It's rare and, well, it's usually so small amount it's near useless. Since AI cheats, you often don't survive long enough for them to reappear.

Comment: Do you have a source for this? Never seen a spice bloom reappear myself.

Comment: Like I said, it's my memory. I remember clearing one area out of spice and later in the game finding a bloom there. It is very possible that it's my memory playing a trick on me, which I noted.